# Privileges page should say when users can access suggested edits queue

Tags: feature-request, bug, edits, privileges

The [Privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) page does not state at what reputation level a user is granted access to the review queue for approving suggested edits.

It *does* say that at 2K reputation, your edits are applied immediately.  And if you go to the [Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review) page without enough reputation, it tells you that you need 2K reputation to access that queue.

It seems to me that the [Privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) page should state this.  The [Privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) page *does* state that at a reputation of 500, users are granted access to the First Posts and Late Answers review queues.

Thoughts?

Comment: The summary in the Privileges page is pretty much broad-strokes-only, and there's a lot of detail that you only have any idea exists by visiting each page in turn. This is just one out of several such "wait, that's a thing?" gotchas. (Flag as dupe only at 50 rep? Huh?)

Answer (score 4):

Just click on the 2k reputation tier you mentioned:

> **Reviewing suggested edits**
>
> In addition, users with this privilege level can also begin reviewing suggested edits (which previously you would have had to suggest). These edits remain in a pending state until they get enough votes to either approve them and make the edits take effect or reject them and discard the edit. Two votes in either direction will finalize the action, except on Stack Overflow where three votes are required.
>
> Aside from reviewing suggested edits, the low quality posts queue is also made available. This queue contains posts which were deemed of low quality by the system. Users are charged with the task of editing to improve their formatting and content, recommending deletion if it doesn't belong on our site, or marking that it is an acceptable post.

Comment: Okay... But there are other cases on the Privileges page where multiple privileges that are awarded at the same reputation level are listed.  For example, both *edit community wiki* and *create chat rooms* are listed, yet they are both awarded at a reputation level of 100.  So there is a precedent for what I'm requesting.

Comment: @Sildoreth A fair point, however, those are (probably) listed as separate items because they don't fall under the same category. Since reviewing suggested edits is already encapsulated by "edit questions and answers", my guess is that it didn't merit separate item on the list. The brief description ("Edits to any question or answer are applied immediately") could be edited to indicate that reviewing is awarded with that permission level as well.